# Why is the database of a Meteor app that has been run once (and never loaded) taking up nearly 3GB?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

**UPDATE:** this was fixed after Meteor v0.4 (2012). For historical purposes:

---

Excerpt from `du`:

```
2890768 ./Code/Meteor/QuarterTo/.meteor/local/db/journal
2890772 ./Code/Meteor/QuarterTo/.meteor/local/db
2890776 ./Code/Meteor/QuarterTo/.meteor/local
2890788 ./Code/Meteor/QuarterTo/.meteor
2890804 ./Code/Meteor/QuarterTo
```

I merely ask because it was in my Dropbox and pushed me over my limit.

Comment: This was *asked* in 2012. You just downvoted an 18-month old question for having been fixed. The supposed duplicate was asked four days after this question. This question almost directly led to the issue being fixed.

Comment: Sorry, I mistook the original and the duplicate; reverted the downvote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When `meteor run` is executed, it starts mongodb with default mongo settings, so it creates (massive) prealloc files in `.meteor/local/db/journal`.

There is no obvious way to disable this behavior. What I have done as a workaround is change the file `app/lib/mongo_runner.js` and add a `--nojournal` parameter that gets passed to mongodb at startup.

I created an issue for this: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/15

Comment: This is fixed in git and will be in the next release. Nice catch!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use smallfiles=true parameter for mongoDB? It will create smallest prealloc files

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off preallocation by passing the --noprealloc arg to mongod. The downside is that there will be pauses each time a new storage file needs to be allocated. Depending on the filesystem you are using (e.g., ext3 vs. ext4), this could result in noticeable latency for a user.

Answer (score 1):

The commands that work for me are:

1. stop mongodb instance if it is running

`sudo service mongod stop`

2. create new mongodb instance without requiring 3+GB preallocated space and use smallfiles.

`mongod --noprealloc --smallfiles`

If you are getting “ERROR: dbpath (/data/db) does not exist.” when running 2, 
then run these commands before 2. 
`sudo mkdir -p /data/db/`

`` sudo chown `id -u` /data/db ``