# Why did Meteor v0.4.x (MongoDB?) use to take up ~3GiB of disk space for a very simple app?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

**UPDATE**: this was fixed after Meteor v0.4 (2012). For historical purposes:

---

I'm testing Meteor on a micro EC2 Ubuntu 11.10 instance (8GiB) and upon installing it and logging in I ran the `df` command to see how much memory had been consumed by core files (about 10%):

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1             8256952    782068   7055456  10% /
udev                    295276         4    295272   1% /dev
tmpfs                   121248       148    121100   1% /run
none                      5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                    303112         0    303112   0% /run/shm
```

Upon installing NodeJS & NPM I again ran `df` to determine how much more room had been consumed and it didn't look like much (an additional 2%):

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1             8256952    919444   6918080  12% /
udev                    295276         4    295272   1% /dev
tmpfs                   121248       148    121100   1% /run
none                      5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                    303112         0    303112   0% /run/shm
```

I then went about installing MongoDB, and as expected, this took quite a lot more memory (59% of disk space in use):

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1             8256952   4585884   3251640  59% /
udev                    295276         4    295272   1% /dev
tmpfs                   121248       148    121100   1% /run
none                      5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                    303112         0    303112   0% /run/shm
```

However, upon installing Meteor, `curl install.meteor.com | /bin/sh` creating the sample myapp from their site `meteor create myapp` and running myapp `cd myapp` & `meteor` I successfully saw the app in the browser displaying "Hello World" (etc), on the terminal side I saw this:

```
[[[[[ ~/myapp ]]]]]

Initializing mongo database... this may take a moment.
Running on: http://localhost:3000/
^C
```

Upon closing the server I checked `df` one last time and was surprised to see a disk full!?

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1             8256952   7778748     58776 100% /
udev                    295276         4    295272   1% /dev
tmpfs                   121248       148    121100   1% /run
none                      5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                    303112         0    303112   0% /run/shm
```

My question is: why did Meteor (MongoDB?) take up ~3GiB disk space for a very simple app?

Is there a way of reducing this consumption of disk space?

Thanks!

Comment: `df -h` may be easier to read than `df`.

Comment: Thanks Joe, will keep in mind for next time! =)

Comment: wait, so deploying meteor & dependencies filled up 8GB of space!?

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos - This was back when Meteor was v0.4.x, it doesn't take up this much space any more at v0.5.7 (see answer below).

Comment: I read the answer, a bit confused by one thing: Is it turned off for "development mode" or solved for all environments?

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos it's solved for all environments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is fixed on the development branch of meteor and will be in the next release.

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/6042b91a9ca75fc47b2477e613da093f1c9b943e

It seems mongo defaults to using huge files and has to be told not to. Understandable for the normal use case of mongo, I guess. By preallocating big files they can improve performance in some cases.

Answer (score 5):

MongoDB [preallocates 3GB for its journal](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Journaling+Administration+Notes#JournalingAdministrationNotes-PreallocFiles%28e.g.journal/prealloc.0%29) the first time it starts up. Meteor should probably turn this off in development mode by default.

Answer (score 0):

The reasons for this large allocation and the work-around have been discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119289/why-is-the-database-of-a-meteor-app-that-has-been-run-once-and-never-loaded-ta) thread. Have checked the --noprealloc option and it works fine.